# $templateCache not retrieving file (Object {id: "templates", size: 0})?

Tags: angularjs

I can access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/template/alert.html` directly in the browser so the file exists. However I get undefined when trying to retreive the file.

```
$templateCache.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/template/alert.html')
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log($templateCache.info()); // <-- Object {id: "templates", size: 0}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You have to put the template into the cache first. Are you doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$templateCache` is not populated automatically. You can [configure](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) `$http` or `$resource` to do that as you make queries, but for other scenarios you'll need to populate it manually.

Example from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

Comment: I did read that from the documentation, however I have the html file I would like to load on the server in the `alert.html` file!

Comment: `$http.get` fixed it for me!

Comment: Good point, are you doing this so you can concatenate/minify all of your HTML templates into one file? There are gulp/grunt plugins that will do this for you as a step in your build process. Doing it at run time is less handy, b/c you have to make additional requests to load each template. Glad you've got it working though!

Comment: Yea I'm using gulp for everything, love it! I need this `alert.html` file because it's likely that it will be appended into the body more than once. Otherwise I'd put it straight into the index.html file.